# How can an ExtJS item config be changed within the handler of itself?

Tags: extjs, properties, handler, config

How can I remove the icon in this actioncolumn item within its handler?

```
                    {
                        header: 'Activate',
                        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                        align: 'center',
                        width: 30,
                        sortable: false,
                        items: [{
                            icon: './Scripts/extjs/examples/shared/icons/fam/accept.png',
                            tooltip: '',
                            handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);

                                if (rec.get('status') == '1') {  // if active, don't show icon
                                    this.up('actioncolumn').icon = '';
                                }

                            }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it can't - configs are applied at initialization time, and sadly the ExtJS API doesn't always provide ways to change things as easily as they are specified in configs.

In the case of an ActionColumn, you can see [in the source](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Action3.html#Ext-grid-column-Action) that the `icon` is used to generate a renderer function in the constructor and there's no way to set it afterwards.

To dynamically decide whether to show an icon or not, you'll need to use `iconCls` instead, see [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?113590-Hide-icon-in-action-column-for-particular-row).

Comment: Implemented a "getClass: function(value, metadata, record) {" function to the item.  Worked perfectly!